# setCompoundDrawables button android not showing images

Tags: android, gridview, android-button

I want to create button with image in grid view below is my code:

My FragmentHome.java:

```
package com.erlanggastudio.myagri.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.R;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.adapters.AdapaterGridView;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.adapters.AdapterGridViewItem;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.adapters.AdapterImageSlider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentHome extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    //For Page Viewer Dots
    //private ImageButton btnNext, btnFinish;
    private ViewPager intro_images;
    private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
    private int dotsCount;
    private ImageView[] dots;
    private AdapterImageSlider mAdapter;
    private int[] mImageResources = {
            R.drawable.image_header_1,
            R.drawable.image_header_2,
            R.drawable.image_header_3
    };

    GridView gridview;
    AdapaterGridView gridviewAdapter;
    ArrayList<AdapterGridViewItem> data = new ArrayList<AdapterGridViewItem>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        intro_images = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPage1);

        pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);

        mAdapter = new AdapterImageSlider(getActivity(), mImageResources);
        intro_images.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        intro_images.setCurrentItem(0);
        intro_images.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        setUiPageViewController();

        gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_product),0));
        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_cart), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_cart),1));
        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_checkout), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_checkout),2));
        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_info), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_info),3));
        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_profile), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_profile),4));
        data.add(new AdapterGridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_about), ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_about),5));

        setDataAdapter();

        return v;
    }

    // Set the Data Adapter
    private void setDataAdapter() {
        gridviewAdapter = new AdapaterGridView(getActivity(), R.layout.lsv_item_mainmenu, data);
        gridview.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);
    }

    private void setUiPageViewController() {

        dotsCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);

            pager_indicator.addView(dots[i], params);
        }

        dots[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));
        }

        dots[position].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Adapter code is :

```
package com.erlanggastudio.myagri.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.R;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityAbout;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityCart;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityCheckout;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityInformation;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityMenuCategory;
import com.erlanggastudio.myagri.activities.ActivityProfile;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapaterGridView extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterGridViewItem> {
    Context mContext;
    int resourceId;
    ArrayList<AdapterGridViewItem> data = new ArrayList<AdapterGridViewItem>();

    public AdapaterGridView(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<AdapterGridViewItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (itemView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.btnItem = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu);
            holder.txtItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }

        final AdapterGridViewItem item = getItem(position);
        holder.btnItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getPoss() == 0) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityMenuCategory.class));
                } else if (item.getPoss() == 1) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityCart.class));
                } else if (item.getPoss() == 2) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityCheckout.class));
                } else if (item.getPoss() == 3) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityInformation.class));
                } else if (item.getPoss() == 4) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityProfile.class));
                } else {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ActivityAbout.class));
                }
            }
        });
        holder.btnItem.setCompoundDrawables(null, item.getImage(), null,null);
        holder.txtItem.setText(item.getTitle());

        return itemView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button btnItem;
        TextView txtItem;
    }

}
```

And layout code is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm try to show dinamicly image in button using :

```
holder.btnItem.setCompoundDrawables(null, item.getImage(), null,null);
```

But the image in button not showing, this is my result:

[image]

any wrong with my code or i'm miss shomething.....???

Comment: Why you need to show compound drawable? you can change this button to ImageView..

Comment: i'm using button cause i need button hover when user pressed the button, and i don't wan't to using imageview and using hover for image.....

Comment: You can use the ImageView or ImageButton, just search for it you get answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
 holder.btnItem.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,item.getImage(),0,0);
```

Comment: nit: two dots `.` here inside `btnItem..setCompound...`, I tried to edit this answer, but SO says: `Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?`